# Group by query and filtered by Max date

Tags: entity-framework, group-by, max

I am trying to get the entities of my table grouped by an ID and filtered by MAX date, but I am not capable to do it with Entity Framework.

```
SELECT * FROM My_table UI
INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT idgroup, MAX(filter_date) AS DateFilter FROM My_table 
    WHERE license = 1
    GROUP BY idgroup
  ) T 
  ON T.idgroup= UI.idgroup AND T.DateFilter = UI.filter_date
  WHERE license = 1
```

My solution for that right now is a StoredProcedure, but I think that this could be possible with EF, but I do not know how to do it.

**Anyone know how to do that with EF statement?**

My_table is already mapped as a EF entity in my project.